# How can I get both tables to have identical column widths?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 tables on different pages. Both tables have the same first 2 columns. The first column is a TearSheet image, and the second column is a checkbox.

Both can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/VH4Q8/1/

I'm having difficulty getting the first 2 columns in both tables to have the same width, even though in each table the first column is assigned the class `tearsheet-image` and the second column is assigned the class `fund-compare-column`, which have widths specified as follows:

```
.tearsheet-image {
    width: 13px;
}

.fund-compare-column {
    width: 13px;
}
```

What do I need to do in order to make both have the same column widths for the first 2 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS you have `table {width:100%}`

This is contradictory to your 13px/13px/250px requirement.  So something has to give I guess.

I find the cleanest way to control the column widths of a table is with the `<col>` element:

```
<table>
  <col class="tearsheet-image">
  <col class="fund-compare-column">
  <thead>
    ...
```

... then you don't have to specify the column's class on every cell of every row.  However not all style properties will be applied if I remember correctly, but widths and backgrounds are, but text-alignment is not :(.

Comment: Thanks for this, for providing clarity. It turns out the 250px specification is unnecessary on the second table so I've just removed that. I guess that's what I get for cutting corners and copy/pasting code.